# How to aggregate MongoDB the final total sum? From the sum calculated earlier

Tags: java, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to aggregate  the final total sum? From the sum calculated earlier

this is original result.

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "prices": 10,
  },
  {
    "name": "a",
    "prices": 20,
  }
]
```

but i need to do this.

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "prices": 10,
  },
  {
    "name": "a",
    "prices": 20,
  },
//i need to do more//
  {
    "name": "total",
    "total":30
  }
```

]

this is example picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ3pu.png)

Comment: Please add sample documents and the query used to 1st result set.

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar  I added an example image to make it easier to understand. Thank you for looking at my problem. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ3pu.png

Comment: Does the original result mean these are the documents in the DB? or the outcome of  a aggregation pipeline ?

Comment: I get query the documents in the database. to jsonString and to put it in csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$group` by null and construct array of root documents in `docs`, get total price in `totalPrices`
- concat current `docs` and total prices doc using `$concatArrays`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `docs` array
- `$project` to show both the fields from `docs` object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
      totalPrices: { $sum: "$prices" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      docs: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$docs",
          [
            {
              name: "total",
              prices: "$totalPrices"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$docs" },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$docs.name",
      prices: "$docs.prices"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XLTNP5bh0t5)

Comment: thank you very much for Answer and explanation.

Comment: Awesome, Nice one ++